# "Undefined control sequence" Regression table from Stata

Tags: tables, undefined, statistics

I am completely new to LaTeX. I work in the TeXworks editor. I would like to create regression tables with results from Stata for my master's thesis. Using the Stata command "esttab", I created a .tex file with code for my table, however when I try to typeset the table to a pdf document, i always get an "!Undefined control sequence" error.

The following is the .tex file which is created by Stata, I only added the "\documentclass{article}", "\usepackage{booktabs}", "\begin{document}" and "\end{document}" commands.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Regressions Strictly Independent\tab{tab1}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}}
\toprule
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}\\
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Linear Regression}&\multicolumn{1}{c} 
{Quadratic Regression}\\
\midrule
main                &                     &                     \\
Strictly Independent&   0.0000152         &                     \\
                &     (0.720)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
CEO\_Comp\_SHBased=0  &           0         &                     \\
                &         (.)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
CEO\_Comp\_SHBased=1  &     -0.0106         &                     \\
                &     (0.110)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
Relative Deal Value &    -0.00958         &                     \\
                &     (0.118)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
Log Board Size      &     -0.0109\sym{*}  &                     \\
                &     (0.060)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
Log Market Cap Acq  &    -0.00177\sym{**} &                     \\
                &     (0.046)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
Average Director Tenure&    0.000415         &                     \\
                &     (0.381)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
CEO\_BM=0            &           0         &                     \\
                &         (.)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
CEO\_BM=1            &    -0.00525         &                     \\
                &     (0.458)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
CEO\_Dual=0          &           0         &                     \\
                &         (.)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
CEO\_Dual=1          &   -0.000284         &                     \\
                &     (0.902)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
Dummy\_Tar\_Listed=0  &           0         &                     \\
                &         (.)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
Dummy\_Tar\_Listed=1  &    -0.00689\sym{***}&                     \\
                &     (0.007)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
Country\_Dummy=0     &           0         &                     \\
                &         (.)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
Country\_Dummy=1     &    -0.00279         &                     \\
                &     (0.189)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
Industry\_Dummy=0    &           0         &                     \\
                &         (.)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
Industry\_Dummy=1    &     0.00913\sym{**} &                     \\
                &     (0.020)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
Cash\_Dummy=0        &           0         &                     \\
                &         (.)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
Cash\_Dummy=1        &     0.00626\sym{*}  &                     \\
                &     (0.062)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
CEO\_Comp\_SHBased=0 $\times$ Avg\_Tenure&           0         &                     
\\
                &         (.)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
CEO\_Comp\_SHBased=1 $\times$ Avg\_Tenure&     0.00118\sym{*}  &                     
\\
                &     (0.067)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
Constant            &      0.0693\sym{***}&    0.000223\sym{*}  \\
                &     (0.001)         &     (0.092)         \\
\midrule
b2                  &                     &                     \\
Constant            &                     & -0.00000251\sym{*}  \\
                &                     &     (0.093)         \\
\midrule
b3                  &                     &                     \\
Constant            &                     &    0.000124         \\
                &                     &     (0.953)         \\
\midrule
b4                  &                     &                     \\
Constant            &                     &    -0.00965\sym{**} \\
                &                     &     (0.019)         \\
\midrule
b5                  &                     &                     \\
Constant            &                     &      0.0439\sym{**} \\
                &                     &     (0.011)         \\
\midrule
b6                  &                     &                     \\
Constant            &                     &     -0.0117\sym{***}\\
                &                     &     (0.001)         \\
\midrule
b7                  &                     &                     \\
Constant            &                     &    -0.00177\sym{**} \\
                &                     &     (0.042)         \\
\midrule
b8                  &                     &                     \\
Constant            &                     &    0.000844\sym{**} \\
                &                     &     (0.012)         \\
\midrule
b9                  &                     &                     \\
Constant            &                     &    -0.00615         \\
                &                     &     (0.466)         \\
\midrule
b10                 &                     &                     \\
Constant            &                     &   -0.000139         \\
                &                     &     (0.951)         \\
\midrule
b11                 &                     &                     \\
Constant            &                     &    -0.00710\sym{***}\\
                &                     &     (0.008)         \\
\midrule
b12                 &                     &                     \\
Constant            &                     &    -0.00268         \\
                &                     &     (0.246)         \\
\midrule
b13                 &                     &                     \\
Constant            &                     &     0.00895\sym{***}\\
                &                     &     (0.010)         \\
\midrule
b14                 &                     &                     \\
Constant            &                     &     0.00618\sym{**} \\
                &                     &     (0.027)         \\
\midrule
\(R^{2}\)           &       0.051         &       0.055         \\
Adjusted \(R^{2}\)  &       0.041         &       0.044         \\
F                   &       5.178         &                     \\
Observations        &        1207         &        1207         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{p}-values in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.1\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), 
\sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The following is the error message I get:

```
("C:\Users\Ruben\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 
2.9\tex\latex\booktabs\booktabs.
sty")
No file Strict_Indep_3d_95.aux.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...egressions Strictly Independent\tab 
                                              {tab1}}}{\thepage }}
l.9 ...Regressions Strictly Independent\tab{tab1}}

?
```

Can somebody help me please?

Remember, I am totally unexperienced with LaTeX/TeXworks/... I am just a guys who would like to have nice regression tables in his master's thesis.

Comment: `\tab` is not a defined command. I would _guess_ that you intended `\label`

Comment: if the `\tab` part is being generated, stick `\newcommand\tab[1]{\label{#1}}` before `\begin{document}` to define `\tab` to be `\label`

Answer (score 5):

If the `\tab` (which is not a command defined in any standard package as far as I know)  part is being generated, stick

```
 \newcommand\tab[1]{\label{#1}}
```

before `\begin{document}` to define `\tab` to be `\label`.

Note however the latex generator you are using would not have generated `\tab` by accident it possibly is intended to be used with a custom package that defines the commands it uses.